# Flash: Stream a RTSP 3GP video, is it possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, streaming, rtsp

**Situation:** I've got a RTSP stream with a 3GP video, users need to watch it in their browser. I can't rely on any proxy setups (RED5/Wozwa etc.) because of scalability.

**Question:** Is it possible to stream it in flash? (I don't mind any dirty hacks :) )

Answer (score 0):

As of Flash player 10, it is not possible to view an RTSP stream.  You will need to use RTMP or HTTP to view the stream with the flash player.